# How to set final layout renderings to shared layout

Tags: experience-editor

We have assembled pages in the final layout of the Item (In Experience Editor, unfortunately, we didn't switch into shared layout).

We need that renderings copied into the shared layout also.

Is there any way to do this? Or do we need to assemble in the shared layout also?

Any help is appreciated!

I need that setting from code behind.

Comment: No that question related to "clear final layout after changes made it"?

Comment: http://rockpapersitecore.com/2016/07/merging-final-renderings-back-down-into-shared-renderings/
I got an answer from this link. Thanks

Comment: Using sitecore experience editor, change the values to raw and in the page , you can witness two rows - shared and final renderings. You can copy from shared to final and vice-versa. But do have a copy of the page before doing this.